# Postgres Partitioning using sqlalchemy

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, database-partitioning

I'm trying to create table partitioning using sql alchemy.

```
class CustomerData(Base):
__tablename__ = "customer"
__table_args__ = {
    "postgresql_partition_by": 'RANGE (age)'
}
id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
age = Column(Integer)
```

while I declare the above class I get following error during execution:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.NotSupportedError: (psycopg2.errors.FeatureNotSupported) unique constraint on partitioned table must include all partitioning columns
DETAIL:  PRIMARY KEY constraint on table "customer" lacks column "age" which is part of the partition key.
```

But I'm able to create similar schema without making age as a primary_key from pgadmin.

What can I do to create similar schema from sqlalchemy.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html) says

> To create a unique or primary key constraint on a partitioned table, the partition keys must not include any expressions or function calls and the constraint's columns must include all of the partition key columns

The *point* behind - you'll have two partitions for different ages, each with a unique index on `id` on each partition. PostgreSQL will have hard time to avoid storing two rows with a *different age* but with *the same* `id`.

Here demonstrated in *pure* PostgreSQL

```
CREATE TABLE tab (
    id         int not null primary key,
    age        int 
) PARTITION BY RANGE (age);


SQL Error [0A000]: ERROR: unique constraint on partitioned table must include all partitioning columns
  Detail: PRIMARY KEY constraint on table "tab" lacks column "age" which is part of the partition key.
```

So effectively you have to either add the `id` to the partition key (which makes less sense) or remove the `primary key`, partition the table and keep the uniqueness programatically or not use *partitioning* at all if `PK` is required.

Comment: I tried not using any PK at all, but sql still gave an error

"sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Mapper mapped class CustomerData->customer could not assemble any primary key columns for mapped table 'customer'"

documentation says there needs to be atleast 1 PK inorder to create a table via sqlalchemy.

EXPLANATION - https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/faq/ormconfiguration.html#faq-mapper-primary-key

Comment: Make sense @Rishabh: still there are three options: not use SQLAlchemy; not use partitions; partition on the PK column.

Comment: Hi @Marmite, anything feasible using this as reference: https://gist.github.com/l1x/da842434fe072cf466a1